# 2.8 Texture paint gone funny

Tags: texturing

I have tried recalculating the normals but it seems that the brush only paints parts of the mesh and then either 'greys' it or cuts holes in it completely

WTH is going on here?!! Its the default ico sphere and as said I have tried recalculating the normals but it still does this!
[image]

Update blend file with EXACT same problem and steps done previously. Still having this problem!

[image]

Comment: Please upload your file.

Comment: This file works perfectly for me. I can't see this bug.

Comment: Need to see what the brush texture and brush mask settings look like - invariably sometimes a stray texture ends up blocking the brush. Also, save where you are at and append to a new file and see what happens with fresh brush settings.